# Adding affiliation due to a 1-month visit during a salary gap

Tags: mathematics, affiliation, visiting

I worked at *University A* and did a research stay during one month at *University B*; I was not paid by them, but I got funding (from a third agency) thanks to them for accepting my visit during a salary gap, before going to *University C*.

About 80% of the paper I want to submit I wrote in my university, but I finished it at *University B* during said stay, even though my original aim of being at *University B* was another research topic.

I would like to put U A and U B both as affiliations, since the environment in U B boosted my research (and I don't want to be less thankful than I ought). Is it justified to write both affiliations? Or should I write only *University A* as affiliation and thank for hospitality to *University B* and my host there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual practice in this case is not to list University B as an affiliation (since you never had a paid position there) but to mention in the acknowledgments that the work was completed during your visit there.

I wouldn't consider it appropriate to list University B as an affiliation on a paper if, for instance, you were never paid a salary or listed as staff on their institutional website.  I would consider it fine to list the visiting position in a CV, though.

Comment: Thanks. I'll put then just my (ex)-affiliation.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that the *effect* will be different no matter what you put, but the latter (...hospitality...) version seems marginally more honest. Being a visitor at a prestigious place caries some cachet of course.

I don't think that a one month salary gap is going to be any issue, if it is even noticed. But you will mention the funding agency, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write both because you spent some time on it and it doesn't matter what's going wrong. Just do it, man.